# ActiveMQ default port 61616 collides with IANA ephemeral port range

Tags: tcp, port, activemq-classic

ActiveMQ's default port `61616` collides with the IANA recommended range for [ephemeral ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) (`49152-65535`).
This can keep ActiveMQ from binding to `61616` if it is used by an existing TCP connection.

Collisions shouldn't be a problem if the ActiveMQ broker is started on system boot, since the OS would likely start at the low end of the port range and wouldn't collide with `61616` until tens of thousands of TCP connections had been established.
However, collisions are possible if the ActiveMQ broker is restarted any time after boot.

Should ActiveMQ users not be using `61616` for real installs, or should port `61616` be excluded from the server's ephemeral port range during deployment?

Comment: This affects Windows Server 2008 and up, as well as FreeBSD and others that use the full IANA range - but not Linux, which typically uses up to port 61000.  Related, or coincidence?

Comment: This also affects **Windows 10**. Just got this error and came to look up for an answer.  ```C:\WINDOWS\system32>NETSTAT -b | findstr 6161 ===>
  TCP    192.168.1.100:61616    msnbot-65-52-108-236:https  ESTABLISHED``` I guess there is not much to do. Reboot windows (kinda random) or change the ActiveMQ config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice this does not tend to be an issue, as ActiveMQ brokers tend to run on dedicated servers without a lot of outbound connections, and therefore ephemeral port usage. They also run either as a Windows service or Unix daemon, so are able to get that port without any real hassle. In most production settings 61616 is used.